# run sharepoint powershell commands without admins role

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I need to create SharePoint web page so I can through it run power shell scripts to grant permission for groups on SharePoint sites content if I am site collection administrator and I do not have permission on SP farm

Answer (score 0):

If you are a site collection administrator, you could run PowerShell scripts to grant permission for groups on SharePoint site contents.

Which contents do you want to grant permission?

Comment: the entire site

Comment: You should be a site collection administrator.